# Draggable dialog with custom directive | Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, draggable, angular-directive

Every dialog in my app looks more or less like this:

```html
<custom-dialog-container>
    <custom-dialog-header>...</custom-dialog-header>
    <custom-dialog-content>
        ...
    </custom-dialog-content>
    <custom-button>
        ...
    </custom-button>
</custom-dialog-container>
```

I am using a `custom-dialog-header` directive in each dialog and I discovered recently the way of applying draggable effect to dialogs by such directive:

```js
import { DragDrop } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'custom-dialog-header, [customDialogHeader]'
})
export class CustomDialogHeaderDirective {
  @HostBinding('class') class = 'dialog__header';

  constructor(
    element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>,
    dragDrop: DragDrop
  ){
    const availablePanes = document.getElementsByClassName('cdk-overlay-pane');
    const latestPane = availablePanes.item(availablePanes.length - 1);
    const dragRef = dragDrop.createDrag(element);
    dragRef.withRootElement(latestPane as HTMLElement);
  }
}
```

So far so good, because everything works almost as expected.
**The only thing missing is handle area restriction to `<custom-dialog-header></custom-dialog-header>` only.**
Now it is set to the whole dialog (even dragging an input from `custom-dialog-content` section can drag the entire dialog).

So here is my question - how am I supposed to implement one? I have read many posts on this topic and the documentation but found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a handle on a specific element using `dragRef.withHandles([element])`. This one should resolve your case.